# JavaScript .click() not working on dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, getelementbyid

Thanks in advance for any help.

I am creating a script to automate a data entry process on a server monitoring website. The site does not have an API for this specific data entry type, so I am using JavaScript to automate the mouse clicking and data entry process. This is my first JavaScript programming ever, so I have no background in this.

I tried setting the value of the box to the value that I need to click on. It sets the value appropriately, however pressing "save" to add the device to the platform does not add the device. The boxes then save null values. I thin this is because an event associated with the correct value is not triggered when the value is set; only when it is clicked.

So I now am attempting to click on the dropdown list and then click on the correct value. I have the correct Id set, but whenever I run multiple lines of code (or the entire script) the dropdown box is not selected.

[image: Dropdown box in question. Plus the value I need to click on]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEqtU.png)
[image: HTML Code for entire dropdown box plus the value and down arrow]

[image: events associated with the combobox]

[image: events associated with the button node]

[image: events associoated with the textbox]

```
window.self = document;

deviceClass = document.getElementById("deviceClassId");

deviceClass.click();
```

I have not tried clicking on the value yet because I cannot even click on the correct dropdown box.

Comment: Are you sure you do not have to trigger the change or input event for it to pick up the value you set?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Comment: Your provided code is unreadable, please always provide code as text, not as images.

Comment: The image of the "dropdown" does not look like a standard `<select>` - so it's likely a wrapper.  Most wrappers require an additional call to update the UI - you set the underlying value then refresh the UI.  You might (can't read the code) be setting the input in the wrapper and thus it's not updating the underlying element - the underlying (hidden) element is what gets POSTed.,   An example for [tag:select2] would be `$("select#selectid").val("newvalue").change()`.   But might depend on the wrapper.